# ECONNREFUSED while trying to call Wordpress REST API from NextJS server

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, wordpress, next.js

I'm trying to run a simple example consuming the list of page slugs from WordPress REST API, but I'm facing a very strange behavior.

I have an async function `getPageList()` that simply calls the WP API using `fetch`.

```
const getPages = async (path) => {
  return await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WP_API_URL + "/pages?_fields=slug", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
}
```

Running through the browser, I have no issues calling this method and getting the results:

```
export default function Example() {
  useEffect(() => {
    getPageList().then(pages => console.log(pages))
  }, []); // OK
  return null
}
```

However if I try to execute the same call from the server, inside `getStaticProps`, I receive the error `FetchError: request to http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?_fields=slug failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000`

This is the code snippet:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const pages = await getPageList()
  //(....)
}
```

If I query this URL using Postman or just copy and paste in the browser, it works seamlessly too.

Any ideas on what's going on?

I'm using create-next-app, Node 16.13.0, Wordpress 5.8.2, PHP 7.4.3 running using local development server (`php -S localhost:8000`)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This was related to how I was initiating my PHP built-in server. Changing it to `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000` instead of `localhost:8000` fixed the problem.